# VBA to properly access multi user database

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Excel Add-In project that I'm working on which has multiple users accessing a database on the server.  Currently all the code works and everything processes correctly as long as only one user is accessing the database at a time.  I'm using DAO to access the database and passing an SQL string it to retrieve records using the following lines of code

```
Set db = OpenDatabase(g400DBPath, , True)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

This creates an issue where if more than one person attempts to access the database at the same time, only the first person is able to access it.  I tried changing the recordset line of code to the following

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenSnapshot, , dbOptimistic)
```

but that gives me the following error:  Run-time error '3001: Invalid Argument

How would I go about setting the access to the record set so that multiple users can run the report?  The users are not updating any information in the database at all, everything is read only.

Comment: Look into what ADODB can do for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is: a snapshot-type recordset is always read-only. Specifying any edit lock options will throw a run-time error, since snapshot-type recordsets don't do locking.

I can't reproduce the behavior, but you can try the following:

```
Set db = OpenDatabase(g400DBPath, False, False) 'Read-only can lead to exclusive locks since more specific locks are stored in the DB
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
```

Alternatively, you could try using ADO and disconnected recordsets. DAO doesn't offer that functionality as far as I know.